# Disable (positive) button of AlertDialog by Default

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

How do you disable the positive button of an Android `AlertDialog` by *default*?

It appears to be quite normal to want the positive button (In this case "Save") to be disabled before the user has made a change to the view (In this case an `EditText`.

I know that I can get the button by calling `dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE)` but this call will return null if `show()` hasn't been called yet.

Comment: Did you tried calling create before show?

Comment: You might be better off making a custom Dialog using the `DialogFragment` class.

Comment: It's contained in a DialogFragment class.

Comment: Any chance you might show us some code?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {

    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
        if(condition)
        ((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setEnabled(false);
    }
});

dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 8):

You have to call show() to access alert dialog's buttons. So, just after you call show() on alertDialog, you get the negative button and set it disabled like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
            .setTitle("Title")
            .setMessage("Message")
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
    AlertDialog d = builder.show();
    d.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setEnabled(false);
```

So, its negative button becomes disabled by default.